# can we use Software serial and timer one at the same time or this software use also timer one?

Tags: softwareserial, timers, tinygps

i am using timer1 and software serial for gps data i need to see if we have a problem with connection .
So i made a timer1 that's start before the loop that will wait the gps sending and after 3s if we didn't receive data we will exit the loop of waiting and going to make diffrent thing .

Comment: Doesn't sound like you would need to configure an extra timer for that. Have you thought about using `millis()`?

Comment: a timer conflict on AVR creates a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/35032/does-softwareserial-use-hardware-timer) software serial only you pinchange interrupt and CPU  delay loop. which means it not effect any timer but it might freeze system while transmission.